# Help to identify fantasy series

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to remember a series I read in the early 90s, which I think was written in the 80s.

The main character was a female who was raised Rapunzel like (separate in tower) and ransomed/ hostage off when her mothers country was conquered. It then follows her life as she accompanies the conquering army, eventually 2nd or 3rd book she comes to the attention of the general of the army.

Not sure if I'm mixing a different series but I think she was meant to assassinate the general when she was ransomed, but failed and maybe hid in the army.

Comment: Did the series start with the leader of the invaders being cared for (incognito) in hospital by the girl? I have a vague memory of series similar to your description starting in this way.

Comment: Was the general only half human and partly saurian?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like the Atlan Saga by [Jane Gaskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Gaskell). The novels were written in the 1960s and 1970s, but the 1980s was the time when they were last reprinted.

[Summary of the first book](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1937432.The_Serpent) courtesy of GoodReads:

> In the lost world of prehistory, a girl is born. Is she a goddess? Cija herself believes that she is. For seventeen years her mother, the Dictatress, has kept her imprisoned in an isolated tower. When she is released, it is with a mission: to seduce Zerd, the snake-scaled general of an occupying army--and stab him to death. This fantastic story of love, jealousy and sudden death is unlike anything you have ever read. It grips the imagination from start to finish.

Answer (score 3):

This reminds me on most points as the *[Chronicles of the Black Company](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Company)* series by Glen Cook.

In the first book the military unit, being followed in the multi-novel story arc, rescues a young girl called Darling.  By the third novel she has transformed from a mascot to the leader of the regiment using the name "The White Rose".

Comment: The Black Company books are awesome, but unfortunately I don't think they match the details from the question.