# YA fantasy fiction trilogy 1970-1985 about general who is half human, half reptile

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

In the 80's I read a YA trilogy about a warring general who was half human and half lizard/reptile/dragon whose skin is covered in blue scales. The trilogy follows a young girl who was captured or sold into the war party/entourage and follows her journey as the general conquers lands etc. I can't remember much more but she eventually becomes his mistress or concubine type of slave maybe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help to identify fantasy series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65809/help-to-identify-fantasy-series)

Comment: We don't close story id's as dupes unless they're confirmed to be the same by the OP.

Comment: @TheBeardyMan You should write up your answer again and put it in for this one.

Comment: Thank you - yes @TheBeardyMan this is the series. Much appreciated!

Comment: @TheBeardyMan seconding what eshier said above - write that up as an answer so that we can kick this one out of unanswered tab :)